# How can i set my heroku's django enviroment (especifically DATABASE_URL) in order to keep local and remote database development?

Tags: database, django, heroku

I would like to know how set my setting.py seccion

```
**DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default)
# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')**
```

in order to develop locally and remotelly with heroku's postgres.

If i don't do nothing else... will i have my local and cloud ambient ready?? or Should i create a new enviroment varying with my local postgres's values? Should i modify the setting.py seccion?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

You don't need to pass `default` to `config()`